# Restrict internal usage method caller

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, methods

Say I have a class `Task` and another class `Subtask` to which the execution of a particular task is delegated but always in the context of a `Task` execution. This implies the `Subtask` always takes a `Task`, and it performs actions on the `Tasks`'s attributes:

```
class Task:
    pass

class Subtask:
    def __init__(self, task):
        self.task = task

    def run(self):
        # performs actions on self.task own attributes
```

Then we have a method in `Task` that makes a specific update. This method is supposed to be used for internal use only:

```
class Task:
    def _update(self):
        # do something restricted
```

But then we actually want to call this method from the `Subtask` to perform those updates:

```
class Subtask:
    def run(self):
        # do stuff
        self.task._update()
```

Here is the issue: this is an irregular behavior. An *internal usage only* method should not be called from another context, and the IDE gives a corresponding warning as expected.

However, I do not want to make the method *public*, `Task.update()`, because it is still of restricted use. We just want to do sort of like friendship as found in C++.

We want to keep that `Task._update()` method *private* but give the `Subclass` class a special permission.

Is there any way to do this?

PS: I know how Python works, I know I can just use that method from outside and ignore the warning, or make it *public* and simply don't use it elsewhere, to summarize: **be responsible**, as it the motto Python proclaims. I agree with this, but I also wonder if there is any way I could achieve what I'm after in a way that makes sense with the Python philosophy.

Comment: Leading underscore doesn't mean class-private. It's as private as you want to treat it. Treating it as module-private or my-library-private often makes more sense than drawing the boundaries at class lines.

Comment: How do you make a method module- or library-private?

Comment: @LiamBohl: You don't make it any sort of private. You just treat it that way. A leading underscore conventionally indicates that the thing so named is an implementation detail, but it doesn't mean that all accesses to that implementation detail should happen in the same class. Heck, the leading underscore convention isn't limited to occurring within classes; for example, a module-level function named with a leading underscore should also be considered an implementation detail.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the most Pythonic solution would be to use private variables, since they are accessible anywhere if you are explicit.

```
class Task:
    def __update(self): # Two underscores for private
        # do something restricted

class Subtask:
    def __init__(self, task):
        self.task = task

    def run(self):
        # Do stuff
        self.task._Task__update() # Access private method
```